# Firefox addons and extensions: getting user input

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, user-input, dom-events

**The setup:** Say you click somewhere on this page, and you've got a Firefox extension that responds by inserting a `<div>` with an `<input type="text">` into the document, positioned at the spot where you clicked.

**The problem:** I can't seem to get this text field to accept user input. It almost seems to be read-only. Is there some sort of configuration I have to set in chrome.manifest or elsewhere? Is getting user input this way allowed in Firefox extensions? If so, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Note: I've been able to set the value by using `prompt();` but I'd rather just type in the `<input>` like normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `event.preventDefault()` to trap mouse clicks? That could be the reason why the text box seems read only – it can never gain focus. To fix this, use:

```
textbox.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

This would keep the click event from bubbling up to your general event handler used to intercept most mouse clicks.

Comment: Thank you! This seems so obvious now, but hadn't even occurred to me. The `event.stopPropagation();` was actually on the `keypress` event handler. Totally forgot it was in there.